# GitHub Action nginx reverse proxy vue.js and Node.js server

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, github-actions, cicd

I would like to create a CI/CD pipeline with GitHub Action to create a nginx reverse proxy server for my vue.js frontend and for my NestJS server.

What I have done so far:

1. When I push or pull a request on the main branch, I run the tests.
2. If the tests pass, build the frontend and backend.

What I want to do now:

3. Create a docker image of the nginx reverse proxy server for my frontend and backend and push it to the docker registry.

```yaml
name: CI/CD Pipeline - Runs All tests and if all pass, builds the frontend and backend and deploys and configures the nginx proxy server to serve the frontend and backend.
# 1) on push or pull request to main branch
# 2) run frontend and backend tests
# 3) if tests pass, build the frontend and backend and save the build artifacts (./WEB/dist and ./BACKEND/dist)
# 4) if build succeeds, create a docker image of the nginx proxy server and push it to the docker registry
# 5) if tests fail or build fails, do nothing

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  backend-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js 16.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.x
          cache: 'npm'
          cache-dependency-path: 'BACKEND/package-lock.json'

      - name: Execute Backend Unit tests
        run: |
          npm ci
          npm run test
        working-directory: ./BACKEND

  frontend-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js 16.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.x
          cache: 'npm'
          cache-dependency-path: 'WEB/package-lock.json'

      - name: Execute Frontend Unit tests
        run: |
          npm ci
          npm run test
        working-directory: ./WEB

  build-frontend:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [backend-tests, frontend-tests]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js 16.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.x
          cache: 'npm'
          cache-dependency-path: 'WEB/package-lock.json'

      - name: Build Frontend
        run: |
          npm ci
          npm run build
        working-directory: ./WEB
      - name: Save Frontend Build Artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: frontend-build-artifacts
          path: ./WEB/dist

  build-backend:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [backend-tests, frontend-tests]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js 16.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.x
          cache: 'npm'
          cache-dependency-path: 'BACKEND/package-lock.json'

      - name: Build Backend
        run: |
          npm ci
          npm run build
        working-directory: ./BACKEND
      - name: Save Backend Build Artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: backend-build-artifacts
          path: ./BACKEND/dist
```

I tried to do it with this action:

But I don't know how to create a docker image of reverse nginx proxy server and push it to docker registry with this action.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: do you have Dockerfile in your repo ?

Comment: no but I think I can build both applications in the workflow. If you have other ideas don't hesitate! I don't know much about it.

Comment: you should have a Dockerfile each of your folders (frontend, backend) and and then use docker to build them and push them to your registry after saving the registry credentials in github secrets... search on google there are a lot of examples of that workflow